# install cloudera impala shell on mac os x and connect to impala cluster

Tags: macos, shell, cloudera, impala

We have impala server on prod and I need connect to it with impala shell from my local macbook w/ mac os x (10.8).

I downloaded `Impala-cdh5.1.0-release.tar.gz`, unarchived it, tried `buildall.sh` which failed: `.../bin/impala-config.sh: line 123: nproc: command not found`

Trying `impala-shell` directly also fails:

```
$ shell/impala-shell 
ls: /Users/.../Impala-cdh5.1.0-release/shell/ext-py/*.egg: No such file or directory
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/.../Impala-cdh5.1.0-release/shell/impala_shell.py", line 20, in <module> 
 import prettytable
ImportError: No module named prettytable
```

I have jdk installed and JAVA_HOME is set.
Cloudera manager seems doesn't support mac os, does it?

Comment: Didn't anybody connect to impala from mac os shell? ((

Comment: Did you try filing a bug report with Cloudera?

Comment: Are you trying to install impala on mac, or just connect to it from your mac? We have impala installed on a linux cluster, and once I SSH into the cluster and type 'impala-shell' from the command line, I have zero issues.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your limited error message:

```
.../bin/impala-config.sh: line 123: nproc: command not found
```

I'd say that no, this package from cloudera doesnt support OSX.   `nproc` is a linux command, and anything that references it isn't going to work on OSX.

If you could provide more information - such as where you downloaded it, or what it is, for those of us who aren't cloudera customers, we might be able to devise workarounds.

Or, contact cloudera support and complain about the lack of OSX support?

Your second error message looks like python, not java - and you provide no context around it....